# Symfony2 Security Component And Propel, Incorrect table name in the select statement

Tags: symfony, propel

I read [this page](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/the-symfony2-security-component-and-propel.html) for manage my symfony2.0 login form with propel orm.
On form submit propel returns this error:

```
Warning! Unable to execute SELECT statement 
[SELECT admin.ID, admin.USERNAME, admin.PASSWORD, admin.USERLEVEL, admin.MERCATO_ID 
FROM `` `admin` WHERE admin.USERNAME=:p1 LIMIT 1] 
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '']
```

It should be

```
FROM admin
```

and not

```
FROM `` `admin`
```

Why in the select statement there is `` before the table name admin ?

**EDIT**

security.yml content

```yml
security:
    providers:
        custom_provider:
            id: papernet.secured.security.provider
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login_firewall:
          pattern:    ^/login$
          anonymous:  ~
        secured_area:
            pattern:  ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

`papernet.secured.security.provider` is my custom provider as is shown in the guide

Comment: Could you show us more config? Like the `app/config/security.yml` ?

Comment: Added the security.yml, but the error seems to be a bug on how propel creates the select statement

Comment: could you paste your `schema.xml`?